# Why is the LINQ to SQL database not persisted in the WP7 emulator?

Tags: linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to persist a very simple username/password combo in WP7 7.1 beta 2 using LINQ to SQL. So far everything works as expected (using the repository/model classes below)

I can create a new database, insert a record and query for that row (and it returns the persisted user no problem). But the next time I spin up the emulator the db context returns false when I exec this expression "db.DatabaseExists()"

Is this normal behavior for the emulator or am I not telling LINQ to persist this between sessions?

Thank you in advance

**repository class**

```
public class UserRepository : IDisposable
{
    private readonly UserDataContext context;
    public UserDataContext Context
    {
        get { return context; }
    }

    public UserRepository()
    {
        context = new UserDataContext(UserDataContext.DBConnectionString);
        CreateDatabase();
    }

    private void CreateDatabase()
    {
        if (context.DatabaseExists() == false)
        {
            context.CreateDatabase();
        }
    }

    public User GetByID(int id)
    {
        return context.GetTable<User>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.UserId.Equals(id));
    }

    public User GetByUsername(string username)
    {
        return context.GetTable<User>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.UserName.Equals(username));
    }

    public void Save(User user)
    {
        if (user.UserId > 0)
        {
            context.GetTable<User>().Attach(user, true);
        }
        else
        {
            context.GetTable<User>().InsertOnSubmit(user);
        }

        context.SubmitChanges();
    }

    public List<User> GetAll()
    {
        return context.GetTable<User>().ToList();
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return context.GetTable<User>().Count();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**model**

```
[Table]
public class User
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**context**

```
public class UserDataContext : DataContext
{
    public static string DBConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/User.sdf";

    public UserDataContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }

    public Table<User> Users;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

The database (and other data) is stored in Isolated Storage on the emulator.  The emulator clears Isolated Storage on shutdown ([see the first Note in MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134796%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx)), so your database is deleted.

Answer (score 3):

The Isolated Storage Explorer lets you create and restore snapshots of the Emulator's isolated storage.  You might want to explore using this to save the state of your database prior to closing down the emulator, and then restoring it once you restart the emulator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408(v=vs.92).aspx